# Propositional Logic with Two Statements

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am given two statements. Letting

$s(x)$ denote "$x$ is a car"
and
$h(x)$ denote "$x$ is manual"

I have to formalise the following statements:

1. "Some car is manual"

Which I think can be denoted as $\exists x\; (s(x) \land h(x))$, but I'm unsure if this is the correct way to put the two statements together.

2. "Not all cars are manual"
3. "All cars are automatic"
4. "There is an automatic car"
5. "Every car is manual"

Comment: I agree with your answer to #1. For #2 you might want to start by thinking about the negation of the statement.

Comment: @SamuelCoskey What's confused me with that one is whether to use $\exists$ or $\forall$. I've thought it could be written as, possibly, $\lnot \forall \; x\;(h(x) \land s(x))$ or maybe as $\forall \lnot x \;(h(x) \land s(x))$

Comment: You did fine on #1. "Some car is manual" means there is at least one thing that is a car and is manual. Use that thing as a value of $x$, then $s(x) \land h(x)$. If you write $\lnot \forall x(s(x) \land h(x))$ you're saying that not everything is both a car and manual. That's true if there's an automatic car, or if there's a bicycle (manual transmission, but not a car), or if there's a block of wood (no transmission at all, and not a car). But it doesn't ensure  that there is even _one_ thing that actually _is_ a car and is manual.

Comment: @DavidK Okay, in that case would my positioning of the \lnot symbol in my answer for #2 be correct?

Comment: Oops, for no good reason I thought we were still talking about #1. The formula doesn't quite work for #2 either, because the formula is true if the entire universe contains just ten manual cars and a block of wood, and nothing else.

Comment: @DavidK This is why I was fretting between $\forall$ and $\exists$. I think now that it has to be $\lnot \forall$ and that the equation should be $\lnot \forall x (s(x) \to h(x))$

Comment: Exactly right. Also an answer has been posted that explains this in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > 1."Some car is manual"
>
> Which I think can be denoted as $∃x(s(x)∧h(x))$ , but I'm unsure if this is the correct way to put the two statements together.

$\checkmark$ Yes.   Literally this is "There exists a thing: it is a car and it is manual."   This is indeed "Some car is manual."

> > 2."Not all cars are manual"
>
> What's confused me with that one is whether to use $∃$ or $∀$ . I've thought it could be written as, possibly, $¬∀x(h(x)∧s(x))$ or maybe as $∀¬x(h(x)∧s(x))$

Just do it one bit at a time. "Not"~"$\neg$", "all"~"$\forall x$" , "cars are"~"$s(x)\to$" , "manual"~"$h(x)$".  $$\neg\forall x\big(s(x)\to h(x)\big)$$

"Not (every thing: if it is a car, then it is manual)."

Key point: remember that

- "all things in the category have the property" is $\forall x~\big(C(x)\quad\to\quad P(x)\big)$, and
- "some thing in the category has the property" is $\exists x~\big(C(x)\quad\wedge\quad P(x)\big)$

Can you try your hand at the rest?